# Return result from simple sql query the serial way for mysql on nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql

Can anyone put a simple example where the function accept sql query string and return an array result ?

```
function do_mysql_query(sql_string) {
 :
 :
 return result;
}
```

so i will be able to

```
var answer = do_mysql_query("select * from mytab where id=1");
```

(all the await/async and promises be internal to the do_mysql_query()?)

thank you j.r.

most answers here are using the parallel way.

Comment: Async await is the solution you need to use or find a mysql connector for node.js that has synchronous methods for query execution.

Comment: thank you , can you provide an example?

Comment: Examples are provided in the answers of the linked duplicate questions.